# Cakephp How to access AppController function in ctp file?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am unable to access AppController.php function in my ctp file.

Please check my code:

**AppController**

```
public function commonEmotions($text=null){
        $this->loadModel("Sticker");
        $this->loadModel("Smiley");
        //Smiley
        $getSmiley=$this->Smiley->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Smiley.image','Smiley.symbol')));
        $emotions=$this->Custom->parseEmotions($text,$getSmiley);
        //Sticker
        $getSticker = $this->Sticker->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Sticker.uniq_id','Sticker.image')));
        $message=$this->Custom->parseStickers($emotions,$getSticker);
        return $message;
}
```

View/Messages/news_feed.ctp

```
echo $this->requestAction('/app/commonEmotions/'.$getNewsFeed['News_feed']['news']);
```

When i running my code i am getting fllowing error

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: News_feed [APP\View\Messages\news_feed.ctp, line 188]

Warning (2): Missing argument 1 for AppController::commonEmotions() [APP\Controller\AppController.php, line 51]
```

Comment: Do not put that in the AppController. Put it into a specific controller that extends the AppController. Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: I feel `$getNewsFeed['News_feed']['news']` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
echo $this->requestAction('/app/commonEmotions/'.$getNewsFeed['News_feed']['news']);
```

Do the request to any of your controllers instead of calling the app controller directly

```
echo $this->requestAction('/Smiley/commonEmotions/'.$getNewsFeed['News_feed']['news']);
```

As all your controllers inherit the method from the app controller